# Как спарсить количество просмотров сообщения телеграм?

Tags: python, telegram

Никак не могу найти информацию о том, как получить значения счётчика просмотров на записи в телеграм канале

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_messages